# Authentication is always active in ionic with Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I'm working with ionic and firebase and I'am having a problem in my view login.

The login view, is always showing as authenticated, but in this view the user has not logged in

What I need to do to show unauthenticated this view? Because the user not logged in yet

**PS: I'm using facebook social authentication.**

```
.controller('BeforeLoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth, Auth) {
  /*$scope.login = function() {
    $state.go('login');
  };

  $scope.signUp = function() {
    $state.go('signup');
  };*/

  Auth.$onAuth(function(authData){
    if (authData === null) {
      console.log("No autheticathed");
    } else {
      console.log("Authenticated");
      /*$state.go('tab.dash');*/
    }

    $scope.authData = authData;
  });

  $scope.loginFacebook = function(){
    Auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect("facebook").then(function(authData) {

    }).catch(function(error) {
      if (error.code === 'TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE') {
        Auth.$authWithOAuthpopup("facebook").then(function(authData){

        });
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  };
})

.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth) {
    var endpoint = "https://<NAME>.firebaseio.com/users";
    var usersRef = new Firebase(endpoint);

    return $firebaseAuth(usersRef);
});
```

Comment: If `Auth.$onAuth(function(authData)` gives you auth data, you can be pretty certain that the user is actually authenticated. Keep in mind that Firebase "remembers" authentication state between page transitions. If you want to force the user to log out, call [`$unauth()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-unauth)

Comment: Thanks For your explanation! I called `$unauth()` and it worked.

Comment: I was going to vote to close as a typo with this cause. But others might have the same expectation, so I turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `Auth.$onAuth(function(authData)` gives you auth data, you can be pretty certain that the user is actually authenticated.

Keep in mind that Firebase "remembers" authentication state between page transitions. This happens transparently behind the scenes and you don't have to write any code for it.

If you want to force the user to log out, call `$unauth()`.